# How to show data with ListView in android?

Tags: android, api, listview, retrofit, baseadapter

I would like to show my data that come from server. My result data is shown [get(0); index (0), price: 3800]. I would like to show all data with listview in android. I use BaseAdapter, CustomAdapter. Here Booking object api.

```
[
  {
    "order_id": 13,
    "booking_person": 2,
    "booking_datetime": "2016-07-01 22:30:00",
    "total_amount": 2100,
    "order_details": [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "order_id": 13,
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 3800,
        "sub_total": 3800,
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "order_id": 13,
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 3250,
        "sub_total": 3250,,
      },
      {
        "id": 124,
        "order_id": 13,
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 2100,
        "sub_total": 2100,            
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

BookingActivity.java

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Booking booking = new Gson().fromJson(bundle.getString("Booking"), Booking.class);
List<Booking> bookingList = new ArrayList<Booking>();
bookingList.add(booking);
BookingDetailAdapter adapter = new BookingDetailAdapter(BookingActivity.this, bookingList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

BookingDetailAdapter.clsas

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
Booking booking = list.get(position);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            holder.textView.setText(list.get(i).getOrderDetail().get(0).getPrice().toString());
        }
        return rowView;
}
```

Comment: didi you inflate any view?

Comment: View rowView rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);

Comment: can you paste the complect adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter fills the parent `Booking` object that you have one. But if you pass `order_detail` list to adapter you can see 3 rows.

```
BookingDetailAdapter adapter = new BookingDetailAdapter(BookingActivity.this, bookingList.get(0).getOrderDetail());
```

You should not loop in list. `getView` method will fired for each item that in list.

```
OrderDetail detail = list.get(position);
holder.textView.setText(detail.get(position).getPrice().toString());       
return rowView;
```

Comment: Your list has just one item. `List<Booking> bookingList = new ArrayList<Booking>();
bookingList.add(booking);` You should pass `order_details` list to adapter.

Comment: detail.get(position) doesn't need. Thank you very much. I got it. :)

Comment: I am glad i could help you. If i could, can you upvote or accept correct answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

first, you should parse the result in an object using `Gson` , and pass the result list to the ListAdapter and then, in the getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

Booking booking = list.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getOrderDetail().get(0).getPrice().toString());

    return rowView;
}
```